# files being overwritten with ������

Tags: windows, zip, atom-feed

I'm finding some of my files being overwritten with this symbol: � U+FFFD

a whole file will be replaced with the symbol... seem like it occurs randomly. I cannot find a re-occurring pattern yet.

Has anyone had this happen to them? Any suggestions?

The only thing that has changed in my programming is now I'm zipping files before uploading them... not sure if that is the root cause. Seems unlikely.

On Windows 7

Comment: Check encoding settings of whatever software generates the file content with those characters or those of the software that manipulates accordingly. Maybe a unicode\UTF versus ANSI type deal but open the text document with those character with Notepad++ for example and toggle the encoding settings and from UTF-8 and ANSI and look over the characters with both and see if when looking at ANSI if some character appear looking like extra characters. You may need to strip such character out if you're getting from a web call, etc.

Comment: is it possible that you are experiencing a ransom ware infection? during the period it is encrypting files, you would likely see files go from plaintext to a raw bytestream. If this has been happening for weeks, that is unlikely, and you may want to run a disk scan. if its happened and progressed over just a few hours however, it may be malware encrypting your files.

Comment: Milk Baby - What software are you using when you open up these text files? Please confirm & check any applicable encoding settings to see if you notice any changes in those parts of the document as you toggle. Check the date modified attribute of those files too & see when was the last time that the file was modified. Wondering if this is a viewing issue only with whatever software you use to view these files or that's just the way & the characters are created by the creation process & perhaps it's something at that level that changed. I assume you know for sure these were never there before?